# Cast association changeset for many to many

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this many to many relation between users and facilities:

```
schema "facilities" do    
  field(:name, :string)
  field(:description, :string)    
  many_to_many(:users, User, join_through: "users_facilities")
end

schema "users" do
  field(:first_name, :string)
  field(:last_name, :string)
  field(:email_address, :string)
  field(:username, :string)
  many_to_many(:facilities, Facility, join_through: "users_facilities")
end
```

This is the `changeset_params`:

```
  %{
  name: john,
  users: [%{id: 1286, name: "john doe"}, %{id: 1287, name: "jane doe"}]
 }
```

It works fine for the `has_many` and give me a single changeset for the entire associations. but didn't work for `many to many`.

The `records_struct` have complete facilities association loaded with users
This is the code:

```
    Facility.changeset(records_struct, changeset_params)
    |> Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc(:users)
```

I get changeset returned from Facility.changeset but `Ecto.Changeset.cast_assoc` throws `internal server` error when I try to test it.

Comment: "throws internal server error" Can you post the complete error message? It should be in the server logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your users and facilities are managed independently. In other words, you don't create a new facility within the user's changeset and vice-versa. You want just to bind/associate to already existing entities, right?

For this case, you need [Ecto.Changeset.put_assoc/4](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#put_assoc/4)

Remember that you will need the association to be preloaded before doing `put_assoc`.
Also be sure to set [on_replace](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-associations-embeds-and-on-replace) option in your `many_to_many` associations, like:

```
many_to_many(:users, User, join_through: "users_facilities", on_replace: :delete)
```

For the many to many associations you most likely want a `:delete`.
It means that when you pass associated records in the changeset it will remove associations with the records that were associated before but they are not in the current changeset. It will not delete associated records.